# Pandas: Series of arrays to series of transposed arrays

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

Ok, this is an easy one, I hope.

Using Pandas, I have a Series of 100 equal length Numpy arrays each with 30000 elements. I'd like to quickly transpose them into a series of 30000 arrays with 100 elements.

I of course can do it with list comprehensions or pulling the arrays but is there an efficient Pandas way to do it? Thanks!

UPDATE:

As per the request by @Alexander to make this a better example, here is some toy data.

```
import pandas
s1 = pandas.Series([np.array(range(10)) for i in range(10)])
```

And what I want returned in this example is:

```
s2 = pandas.Series([np.ones(10)*i for i in range(10)])
```

That is, an element-wise transpose of a Series of arrays into a new Series of arrays. Thanks!

Comment: 100 arrays, each with 30k elements. Isn't that a 30k x 100 matrix?  See this question on asking good questions: How to make good reproducible pandas examples http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, this works actually. Any one have a more efficient solution?

```
pandas.Series(np.asarray(s1.tolist()).T.tolist())
```